# migrate cloud dataprep to a different account

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I had to migrate my personal Account to a different email provider,
new Account is Organization Admin of entire GC project.

I can not see any dataprep flow from within my account but I can still access all flow from my old account, is there a quick way to grant access to other accounts and or migrate all the jobs at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Dataprep does not have a built-in way to migrate flows.

The next best approach may be to export the flows as Dataflow templates and then use them in the new account.

Answer (score 1):

As well mentioned by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4644743/james), you need to export the flow from your old account to then import it into the new one. I recommend you to take a look on the following guides to get the step-by-step instructions to perform these actions:

- [Import Flow](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Import-Flow_118228662)
- [Export Flow](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Export-Flow_118228661)

Additionally, you can try to [share](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Share-a-Flow_118228660) or [send a copy](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Send-a-Copy-of-a-Flow_118228659) of the flow, which enables you to work with a completely independent version of the original.